# Linker Flags not inheriting from Frameworks iOS

Tags: ios, entity-framework, linker, cocoapods

Following the tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/81103/introduction-google-maps-ios-sdk-swift) I was told to add the following  Frameworks to my Project

- AVFoundation.framework
- CoreData.framework
- CoreLocation.framework
- CoreText.framework
- GLKit.framework
- ImageIO.framework
- libc++.dylib
- libicucore.dylib
- libz.dylib
- OpenGLES.framework
- QuartzCore.framework
- SystemConfiguration.framework

Now I decided to make a brand new project, so I proceeded to do the same thing...

I added the frameworks, they show up in the framework folder like this but the Pods file looks different:

So in one of my projects I added the frameworks and my Linking settings looked like this:

[image]

And the other looks like this:

[image]

And the same goes for the Pod File in the Frameworks Folder:

[image]   [image: enter image description here[4]]

I did nothing differently. Why might this happen.
Now I get the following error because of this, and can't fix it !!

[image]

Any ideas?  It works in one project, but not in the other

Comment: could you please check the build architecture ? It's in the Build Settings for both the Project and the Target for both projects.

Comment: Standard Architectures (armv7, arm64) , but this shouldn't be the issue, because both projects have the same architecture, yet the project builds on one of them

Comment: how about the linker flags, from the images you posted they are different.

Comment: Exactly, I figured that I could add the `@inherited` to the linker flags,... this solved a lot of my problems. Now I get the error `-bundle_loader can only be used with -bundle` and this error happens when the Mach-O Type is set to either `executable` or `bundle`

Comment: please double check and clean your project. also use capital "B" for Bundle

Comment: I've tried this a few times... no luck

Comment: last resort : delete your "Scheme" on the project that doesn't build and generated it again automatically. You can find that next to your "Stop building button" in Xcode, in the left. "Manage Scheme" and then delete and generate them automatically.

Comment: I restarted my PC, now the project builds, but when I try to run it hangs on `Attaching to iOS Simulator`. Problem after problem. I appreciate all the help

Comment: Delete the app from the simulator by long pressing your mouse on your app icon and build again.

Answer (score 0):

Check your linker flags, then clean your project, try to delete your Scheme and regenerate it automatically and then delete your app from the simulator and build it.

Comment: Deleting app from simulator didn't help, still hanging

Comment: any updates ? Does XCode hang or only the simulator ?